# How to solve this problem about leveling a ground?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, problem-solving

We are given this plot

[image]

from which I extract that $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{1600}-\frac{x}{4}+125$. I am asked to find the height at which the ground should be leveled, in such a way that that the exceeding ground from one side fills the lack of it in the other. Tying to find a procedure, I end up trying to solve the following equation, that is too complicated to be correct:

$$x (\frac{x^2}{1600}-\frac{x}{4}+125) \int_0^x f(x) dx = \int_0^{600}f(x) dx - (600-x)(\frac{x^2}{1600}-\frac{x}{4}+125)$$

This seems to be a nonsense, and any other approach I've tried leads nowhere. Sorry for bothering you.

Comment: $\int_0^{600}f(x)dx$ is the total amount of "dirt". If the width is 600, then what should the height be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide:

If the area under the graph is preserved, then we have

$$600 h = \int_0^{600} f(x) \, dx$$

Just evaluate the integral and then divide by $600$.